# Difference between class and data_class entity field option

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Every time I want to use an entity field, I am always confused between the class and data_class of the entity field options.

I've read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class) in french and in english and I don't seem to figure it out. I would like to have an exemple of use so I could visualise it.

Answer (score 1):

Data_class is not necessary a Doctrine Entity.
It could be usefull if you are using Data Access Object to differenciate Domain Objets than Model Objets

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between class and data_class is that class is used to map data to a Doctrine entity, whereas data_class can be used to map to any object (Doctrine entity or else). 
Correct me if I'm wrong.